# How to center text with CSS?

Tags: html, css

You can view my form here:

http://www.escalateinternet.com/free-quote.php

If you click on the button at the bottom to submit the form, you will see an error message popup saying you need to enter your name.  Can anyone tell me why that error message isn't centered properly?

Here is the code I'm using in the CSS for it:

```
.errorcontainer{
    width:90%;
    height:25px;
    padding-top:17px;
    font-size:12pt;
    font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
    color:#FF0000;
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
}
```

What do I need to change to center my error messages properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues.

1. The parent container `.slickreporting` is set to `position: absolute;`, and is set to `left: 30px;`.  It's also limited to `width: 90%`.  I recommend making `left: 0` and `width: 100%;` so it's center point is in the middle.

   ```
   .slickreporting {
       bottom: 108px;
       left: 0;
       position: absolute;
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Your `.errorcontainer` is set to `width: 90%;` which means it's point of center will be slightly to the left.  Set this also to `width: 100%;`

   ```
   .errorcontainer {
       color: #FF0000;
        display: block;
        font-family: 'Droid Sans',sans-serif;
        font-size: 12pt;
        height: 25px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding-top: 17px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
    }
   ```
3. Remove the default margin/padding from your fieldset (because you are using absolute left positioning, you want all elements to line up):

   ```
   .slickwrap fieldset {
       border: 0 none;
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: I made the suggested changes and it got it almost completely fixed - but it does appear to still be a little off-centered - or possible the button is off a bit.  Are you seeing the same thing?

Comment: Yes, because your parent `fieldset` has padding, the absolute left positioning is causing it to shift slightly.  I've updated my answer with step #3 that removes the default margin/padding from this element.

Comment: Perfect!  Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

The width of the `.errorcontainer` is 90%..

To center it you can set is left/right margins to auto..

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
.errorcontainer{
  width:90%;
  height:25px;
  padding-top:17px;
  font-size:12pt;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  color:#FF0000;
  display:none;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
```

}